# Problems using the '#' to identify tags in a master/content/css page combination

Tags: asp.net, html, css, master-pages

I want to separate the design and implementation of my web pages into a separate HTML and CSS files (for easier maintenance).

I have the following Page defined in a project.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/STGGeneral.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="SystemManager.Register" %>
```

And this makes a reference to the following CSS file

```
#UsernameLabel
{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px;
}
```

The trouble is when ASP.NET generates the code sent to the browser it sends the following

```
   <!-- Login Popup -->
   <input type="image" name="ctl00$LoginButton" id="ctl00_LoginButton" class="LoginButton" src="Images/key.png" style="border-width:0px;" />

   <div id="ctl00_LoginFormPanel" class="LoginPanel">   
        <div id="ctl00_UpdatePanel1">                           
                <span id="ctl00_LabelUsername">UserId:</span>
                <input name="ctl00$UsernameTextBox" type="text" id="ctl00_UsernameTextBox" />            
                <span id="ctl00_LabelPassword" class="StandardLabel">Label</span>
                <input name="ctl00$PasswordTextBox" type="text" id="ctl00_PasswordTextBox" />
                <input type="image" name="ctl00$ConfirmLoginButton" id="ctl00_ConfirmLoginButton" class="ConfirmLoginButton" UseSubmitBehavior="false" src="Images/Security.png" style="border-width:0px;" />                
        </div>
   </div>
```

Because my 'Username' label is now called ctl00_LabelUsername by ASP.NET the style which positions this code тo longer works.

Is there a way of telling ASP.NET that I do not want it to change the name of my objects, or how do you do a reference using '#' within a page generated by a master/content page combination.

Comment: Is there any reason you dont just use a class?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on .NET 4.0, they added ClientIDMode for this purpose

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using ASP.NET 4.0 you can give a class to the Label, like

`LabelUsername.CSSClass = "LabelClass";`

else you can try using the CSS selector like-

```
.LoginPanel span
{
  // CSS Propeties for the label.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Quite simple. You change your css to reference `ctl00_LabelUsername`

Comment: Simple, but not robust. You can't rely on that the way the id is created will stay the same in the future.

Comment: Ooh - bad idea. ctl00_ is an accident and could change.

Comment: Never do this. This will break if you move `LabelUsername` into a different container. It's a total maintenance nightmare.

Comment: -1, if you add a nested masterpage, or want to use this id on another page with a different masterpage it will break.

Comment: Wow what a lot of opinionated comments. The question asked how to reference the label in css. That is what the answer gave. I notice that no one who marked the answer down actually gave a meaningful alternative.